# Pygame: Creating a border

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've been working on my school project which is a 2D game with a moveable player. I wish to create a border around the edge of the screen. I have read through several other articles but can't seem to wrap my mind around it. It would be great if someone could help me. Here is my program

```
import pygame
import os

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)


class Player(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
        self.image2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False) 
        self.coffee = pygame.image.load("coffee.png")
        self.computer = pygame.image.load("computer.png")
        self.background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
        self.flipped = False
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0


    def handle_keys(self):
        """ Movement keys """
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
            self.y += dist 
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]: 
            self.y -= dist 
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
            self.x += dist
            self.flipped = False
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= dist
            self.flipped = True

    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.flipped:
            image = self.image2
        else:
            image = self.image
        surface.blit(self.background,(0,0))
        surface.blit(self.coffee, (725,500))
        surface.blit(self.computer,(15,500))
        surface.blit(image, (self.x, self.y))


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))    #creates the screen

player = Player() 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()      # quit the screen
            running = False

    player.handle_keys()       # movement keys
    screen.fill((255,255,255)) # fill the screen with white
    player.draw(screen)        # draw the player to the screen
    pygame.display.update()    # update the screen

    clock.tick(60)             # Limits Frames Per Second to 60 or less
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is that you can add 20 pixels to each width and height and draw a series of squares all around.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800 + 20, 600 + 20))


for x in range(0, 810, 10)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, BLACK, [x, 0, 10, 10])
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, BLACK, [x, 610, 10, 10])

for x in range(0, 610, 10)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [0, x, 10, 10])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [810, x, 10, 10])
```

Comment: Why not `pygame.draw.rect(surface, BLACK, [0, 0, 820, 10]);` etc?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Where in my source code should i add the syntax?

Comment: Ok, i placed this in the while loop before player.draw(screen). It draws the rectangles perfectly but they don't act as boundaries. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to restrict the movement of the player to only be able to move within the space inside the borders. You've asked many question about the same script during the last 24 hours. Maybe it's better to watch a tutorial instead, learn the basics, and then ask if it's something you don't understand. Here is some good tutorials: [Richard Jones presentation on programming games with pygame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0&index=4&list=PL4Yp6gRH-R1Birdm-Gs-SdBFWLUC1q3Fa) and [pygame official tutorials](http://www.pygame.org/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your main part before `player.draw(screen)`:

```
pygame.init()

line_width = 10
width = 800
height = 600
#creates the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width+line_width, height+line_width),0,32)    

screen.fill(white) # fill the screen with white
# top line
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [0,0,width,line_width])
# bottom line
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [0,height,width,line_width])
# left line
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [0,0,line_width, height])
# right line
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [width,0,line_width, height+line_width])
```

Comment: I placed it there. The program draws the boundary rectangles but the player doesn't move when i hold down the arrow keys, i have to keep tapping the arrow keys for the player to move. Also the boundaries don't work as i can still move out of the screen.

I also tried placing the code outside the loop but that didn't work either. Please do help.

Comment: then you are talking about a completely different issue. Drawing is not restricting the motion.